# How to get a particular field value from multidimensional array in laravel

Tags: laravel, multidimensional-array

I have a variable $cart which stores the details of product. I want to get a particular field from the cart.

dd($cart) show the following result.

```
Cart {#437 ▼
  +items: array:1 [▼
    "airports_334_64" => array:4 [▼
      "qty" => 1
      "price" => 1600000
      "duration" => 0
      "item" => array:28 [▼
        "id" => 64
        "created_at" => "2017-05-29 10:24:22"
        "updated_at" => "2017-05-29 10:26:51"
        "title" => "Airport ad"
        "price" => "120000"
        "location" => "Airport T3"
        "city" => "Delhi"
        "state" => "Delhi"
        "rank" => "12"
        "landmark" => "abc"
        "description" => "<p>new</p>"
        "image" => "1496053462.jpg"
        "references" => ""
        "status" => "Available"
        "display_options" => null
        "light_option" => null
        "airportnumber" => null
        "discount" => "1"
        "slug" => null
        "reference_mail" => "chingkhei91@gmail.com"
        "airports_id" => "64"
        "area" => "arrival_check_in_hall"
        "displayoption" => "backlit_panel"
        "dimensions" => "7'10"x3'9""
        "optionprice" => "1600000"
        "units" => "8"
        "ad_code" => ""
        "variation_id" => 334
      ]
    ]
  ]
  +totalQty: 1
  +totalPrice: 1600000
}
```

I want to get the value of reference_mail i.e Cart->items->item->reference_mail

Comment: So you want all `reference_mail` fields? Because I presume a cart can have multiple items?

Comment: yes.. all fields

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [Collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections) provided by Laravel:

```
$items = collect($cart->items);
$reference_mails = $items->map(function($item){
    return $item['reference_mail'];
});
```

This leaves you with an array of all the reference mails. The behaviour of `map` is described [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-map)

Comment: Getting null value.. Collection {#441 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => null
  ]
}

Comment: @Omikabira I updated the code. Let me know if this works.

Comment: $items = collect($cart->items);
$reference_mails = $items->pluck('item');
$abc= $reference_mails[0]['reference_mail'];

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access them then you should iterate over the items like so.

```
foreach ($cart->items as $items) {
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $email = $item['item']['reference_mail'];
    }
}
```

If you need to access it directly based on array index then you could do this.

```
$email = $cart->items['airports_334_64']['item']['reference_mail'];
```

If you need the list of `reference_mail` then you do this in your query rather than going through all this. If you have a collection then you can use `pluck` method to retrieve the list of emails.

Comment: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() for third foreach loop

Comment: I can't use static value in array

Answer (score 1):

This is an old thread, but I'd like to give a typical Laravel answer for this question. You can use `Illuminate\Support\Arr` to have a clean code, without having to loop and check every dimension of your array:

```
$referenceMail = Arr::get($cart, 'items.*.reference_mail');
```

There are a plenty of other very helpful helpers you can pick from, see https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/helpers#arrays-and-objects-method-list.

Helpers names have changed in v5.7, but you have the equivalent (`Arr::get() => array_get()`, `Arr:has() => array_has()`,...) if you use an older version of Laravel.